# VLookup formula using substitute

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I tried adding vlookup formula in excel with Macro by entering the following formula into the quotes but when I tried running, it gave me the error

> "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

can you please help?

```
Range("A2").formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'sheet1'!B:M,12,FALSE),MID(B2, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2," - ",CHAR(1),2))+1, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2," - ",CHAR(1),3)) - FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2," - ",CHAR(1),2))-4)*0.025)"
```

Comment: To put quotes in your string you need to double up on them.

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE(B2,"" - "",CHAR(1),3)`

Comment: Also, you might want to use `Range("A2").Formula` instead.

Comment: thanks, sorry I did have Range("A2").Formula